# Formatting a BigDecimal in Apache Velocity

Tags: java, currency, velocity, bigdecimal

In my velocity templates, I've been using the Velocity [NumberTool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/NumberTool.html) to format number variables as a currency.
Most of these are primitive doubles and they work fine with this tool.

However, some are of type BigDecimal and they don't seem to be formatted at all.  It'll just show the expression as is when rendered:

```
$global.numberTool.currency($someBigDecimalVariable)
```

Is there a convenient way to format a BigDecimal with Velocity as a currency?  What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can put any object into a Velocity context, the easiest thing to do is to put your own `DecimalFormat` object in your context and call its `format()` method in the template.

Of course this isn't a very nice solution but you can refine it to make it more generic.

Comment: One thing that you have to bear in mind though is that `DecimalFormat` isn't thread-safe. This may or may not be relevant but it's good to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use JSTL in Velocity? I used the fmt JSTL Tags for displaying BigDecimals as a Currency like this:

`<fmt:formatNumber value="${myBigDecimalValue}" type="currency" currencySymbol="€" currencyCode="EUR" minFractionDigits="2" maxFractionDigits="2"/>`

Comment: I seem to remember that Velocity did not allow JSTL, but it's been a while.

Comment: I have no experience in Velocity at all and because he asked for alternatives I thought this might help.